# ¿Cómo cambiar el nombre del proceso javaw.exe de mi programa?

Tags: java, java-8

He leído muchos posts y todos mencionan herramientas con qué hacerlo, pero no he encontrado ningún código de ejemplo.

Por ejemplo, una de las herramientas mencionadas es: http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jsmooth-doc.html#N102D6

Soy totalmente nulo en Java ¿Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Hola @Carlos, según se, desde el comando javaw no es posibles, tendrías buscar un comando de powershell o cmd, porque nativamente no es es posible. Lo mejor seria que escribieras que buscar resolver con ese cambio por si hay otro enfoque posible.

Comment: A qué te refieres con cambiar el nombre del proceso javaw.exe? Los procesos en Windows toman el nombre del archivo ejecutable correspondiente. JSmooth no hace lo que pides. Esta herramienta lo que hace es envolver tú código java dentro de un ejecutable de Windows que posibilita ejecutar tu aplicación como cualquier apliación de este sistema operativo: con doble clic.

Comment: Simplemente quiero un nombre que identifique a mi aplicación. No quiero que aparezca bajo el nombre de "javaw.exe", por esta razón, necesito cambiar dicho nombre.

Comment: La forma más simple que he visto es copiar el archivo `javaw.exe` y cambiarle el nombre, luego con este archivo ejecutar tu programa java y podrás ver en el proceso con el nombre del archivo.

Comment: javaw.exe está en el directorio de instalación de Java?

Comment: si, la ruta según la version es `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin`

Comment: ¿Hay que cambiar algún fichero de configuración para indicar que ese ejecutable sigue siendo javaw.exe o simplemente basta con cambiar el nombre?

Comment: Simplemente cambiando el nombre y cuando vayas a ejecutar en lugar de `java -jar nombreDelProyecto ` ejecutas `nuevoNombreArchivoJava -jar nombreDelProyecto `